# Centring a view at the centre of view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to show an animated spinner while loading a table view.

```
loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 155, 170, 170)];
loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
loadingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
activityView.frame = CGRectMake(65, 40, activityView.bounds.size.width, activityView.bounds.size.height);
[loadingView addSubview:activityView];

loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 115, 130, 22)];
loadingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
loadingLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
loadingLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
loadingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
loadingLabel.text = @"Loading...";
[loadingView addSubview:loadingLabel];

[self.view addSubview:loadingView];
[activityView startAnimating];
```

I have embedded a `UIActivityIndicatorView` within `loadingView`.
The problem that I'm facing is:

1. The loading view is not at the centre of view controller.
2. I'm trying to centre the loading view to the centre of view controller and the `UIActivityIndicatorView` has to be in the centre of loading view but it's not getting centred like the way I'm expecting.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding any of the CGRect values? Most should be calculated based on the size of each view's parent view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In ViewDidLoad add this code it works:

```
[self.view addSubview: loadingView];
loadingView .center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) / 2, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should center it when view controller is laying out the subviews.

For view controllers, [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews) is a good place to do that:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
  self.activityView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.loadingView.frame) / 2, CGRectGetHeight(self.loadingView.frame) / 2);
  self.loadingView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) / 2, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) / 2);
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. `loadingView` needs to centered inside `self.view`. `activityView` and `loadingLabel` are placed within `loadingView`.

Answer (score 0):

set frame:

```
int width = 170;
loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2) - (width)/2, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2) - (height)/2, width, width)];
activityView.frame = CGRectMake((loadingView.frame.size.width/2) -(activityView.bounds.size.width/2), (loadingView.frame.size.height/2) - (activityView.bounds.size.height/2) - 11, activityView.bounds.size.width, activityView.bounds.size.height);
loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((loadingView.frame.size.width/2) - 65, loadingView.frame.size.height - 25, 130, 22)];
```

or

loadingView.center = CGPointMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2), ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2));